# How to indent HTML5 with omitted closing tags properly?

Tags: indentation, filetype-html

I try writing some HTML5 with omitted closing tags in NVIM v0.3.4, and get this:

```html
<ol>
    <li>3
        <li>4
            <li>8
                <li>9
</ol>
```

This is legit HTML5, and even recommended by some. Is there a way to get this fixed? Specifically, to have the following without manual intervention on the indentation:

```html
<ol>
    <li>3
    <li>4
    <li>8
    <li>9
</ol>
```

Comment: I was curious about what w3.org says. One can find similar examples here https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/grouping-content.html#example-51863af6. I tried https://github.com/prettier/prettier which readds the closing tags. So I am sorry I do not have an answer for you.

Comment: I still whine for xhtml2. Browser manufacturers who killed that pretty clear standard have committed a crime against the humanity.